# How can i use Metamask to make transactions?

Tags: flutter, dart, blockchain, ethereum

```
import 'package:http/http.dart'; //You can also import the browser version
import 'package:web3dart/web3dart.dart';

var apiUrl = "http://localhost:7545"; //Replace with your API

var httpClient = Client();
var ethClient = Web3Client(apiUrl, httpClient);

var credentials = ethClient.credentialsFromPrivateKey("0x...");

// You can now call rpc methods. This one will query the amount of Ether you own
EtherAmount balance = ethClient.getBalance(credentials.address);
print(balance.getValueInUnit(EtherUnit.ether));
```

This is the code from web3dart package in flutter. I want to replace the apiUrl with some kinds of url from the Metamask mobile app itself(connected via walletConnect package). Any help guys?

Answer (score 0):

Use this package for Flutter. LINK: https://pub.dev/packages/web3dart

```
var apiUrl = "http://localhost:7545"; //Replace with your API

var httpClient = new Client();
var ethClient = Web3Client(apiUrl, httpClient);

EthPrivateKey credentials = await ethClient.credentialsFromPrivateKey("0x...........");

EthereumAddress address=credentials.address;
print("ADDRESS FORM PRIVATE KEY : "+address.hex);
```